# Using servlet in h:graphicImage

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2

I am having a servlet which is reading images from database, how can i run this servlet in `h:graphicImage` tag so that i can show images in the JSF page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify an URL in the `value` attribute which matches the URL pattern of the servlet mapping. For example, if it is mapped on an URL pattern of `/images/*`, then just do so:

```
<h:graphicImage value="images/foo.png" />
```